# How to normalizeText in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I want to change This:
normalizeText(“This is some \“really\” great. (Text)!?”)
To this:
“THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT”
how can I do it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string = "This is some \“really\” great. (Text)!?"

print(''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum()).upper())
```